# Omitting Spring Data JPA autowiring during tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, autowired

I have a Spring Boot application that uses a library (my own), that has Spring Data JPA dependencies.
Within the library, I'm using JPA repository interfaces and a custom repository fragment that uses a `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface.

I have a configuration inside the library to `@EnableJpaRepositories`, as below:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.package.domain.jpa.repo", bootstrapMode= BootstrapMode.LAZY)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {LookupConfig.class, LookupMapping.class})
@Configuration
public class LookupJpaConfiguration {}
```

I have also declared (not generated) the meta-models (with `_` appended to the class name) for the entity classes in the same package as the entity classes.

The main application is also a `@SpringBootApplication`, with `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.0` as parent. This application uses the library as a dependency, and `@Autowire` a class from the Library. The application itself does not have direct dependencies on Spring Data.

The problem is, I am **unable to run Unit tests without adding properties for the datasource**.

This is what the test class's declaration looks like:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
public class OrderStatusProcessorTest {

    // Uses the library with JPA dependency
    @MockBean private LookupService lookupService;

    // The class being tested; uses LookupService
    private final OrderStatusProcessor orderStatusProcessor;

    public OrderStatusProcessorTest() {
        orderStatusProcessor = new OrderStatusProcessor(lookupService);

    }
...
```

I have already tried `@Mock`ing `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory`, but none of those worked either.

**Library's pom file**

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Lovelace-SR5</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

With the current setup, the error I'm seeing is as below --

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    ...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

It does work if I provide the datasource properties correctly. But what I want is for the Tests to run without actually connecting to the database.

Let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are trying to do is called [integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721443/exactly-what-is-integration-testing-compared-with-unit/48187266#48187266). True unit test does not depend of `@SpringBootTest` annotation on class or `@Autowired` on the test class. So this explains why the test are asking for database configuration.

Comment: @Dherik That makes sense. However, I removed the `@SpringBootTest`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@Autowired` annotations, but the problem is still there. The error is exactly the same.

Comment: Try to exclude all Datasource autoconfigs from Spring boot - e.g. @TestPropertySource(properties=
{"spring.autoconfigure.exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})})
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderStatusProcessorTest{...}  - Let me know if that works for you